# HTML SVG as background with unscaled, right-alined content

Tags: html, svg, smil, svg-animationelements

What are the configuration parts? As far as I have it tested, that is what I identified:
- body background-image needs to be set to the SVG
- body background-sizing - to fill the background, i tried 100% 100%
- svg tag's attribute viewBox must contain the original values to define the proportions?
- svg width and height attributes do not do anything?
- svg attribute preserveAspectRatio does not do anthing?
- the svg's content-object is .. well I don't know how to align it to the right

So far the background still scales, and content stays centered.
Any wisdom around on this matter?

```
html,body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: 
        url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px'     viewBox='0 0 366 768'  xml:space='preserve'><rect x='260' style='fill:lime' y='257' width='229' height='142'/></svg>");
}
```

[test case on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BananaAcid/0wptdrbq/)

Thanks folks

edit:
The content should not scale, but the main SVG area should. Having the content always aligned to the right.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want to happen. Do you want it to scale or not? The attributes you quote are functional but it rather depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @RobertLongson In my current case, i want the content unscaled. As well as alined to the right.

Comment: unscaled => no viewBox

Comment: but does it then still resize to fill the target's background and how to make unscaled content stay the same distance to the right border?